# Masterpage and CSS are not applied in IE 8

Tags: css, custom-masterpage, internet-explorer

In SharePoint 2013, I have my custom masterpage. Masterpage uses custom CSS. 
Inside of my custom CSS I have:

```
#suiteBarLeft, 
#suiteBarRight { 
    background-color:#004250;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This piece of code changes color of top bar (this one with Newsfeed, SkyDrive and Sites - suiteBarLeft - and user name, cog wheel - suiteBarRight).

This works perfctly in all modern browsers. Unfortunatelly, my client uses IE8. In this browser, top bar is still blue and gray, just like in standard CSS.

I'm not sure, if this is IE problem with CSS only, or is this something with SharePoint. Does someone have an idea, how can I make my site look the same in all browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After long investigation I found solution. It is both SharePoint and IE 8 specific problem.

IE 8 loads styles in different order, than IE 10. In IE 8, after my custom css, class `.ms-core-needIEFilter` was loaded. The class has gradient inside. 
I added to my custom CSS following code:

```
.ms-core-needIEFilter #suiteBarLeft
{
background-color:transparent;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#004250,endColorstr=#004250)";
}

.ms-core-needIEFilter #suiteBarRight
{
background-color:transparent;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#004250,endColorstr=#004250)";
}
```

where `startColorstr` and `endColorstr` were set to same value as my `background-color`.

Comment: You could also use an `!important` tag in your custom css to override any other element's style no matter when it was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[CSS background-color Property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-color.asp)

According to the page:

> IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE.

So yes, the problem is a very specific thing between IE8 and CSS. You may still get it to work in your customer's jurassic browser by making a small change to your master page, though.

Comment: Masterpage has following doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

While the CSS updates above will work around the issue, another option as mentioned in this [MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/pt-BR/ac8c35a8-fd67-458a-8e64-6dcad5304ef5/globally-disappearing-styles-after-page-load), if you set the IE zoom to 100% the top bar will render correctly.