# Custom CSS will not work on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, master-page, css

I have created a custom CSS file under my (site content --> style library) and I added a reference to this CSS on my master page. I test the layout on chrome, Firefox and IE version10 and it is working well.

But users how are using IE version 8 , complaints from some layout issues, and after checking this I realized that these layout issues are related to the fact that the custom CSS did not apply on IE version8, while if the same users access the SharePoint using chrome there will not be any layout issue

So can anyone advice please?

**My current custom CSS after adding \9 looks as follow:-**

```
div#suiteBarLeft{
background-color: #008CD2;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

div#suiteBarLeft{
background-color: #008CD2\9;
color: #FFFFFF\9;
}

div#siteIcon{ 
display: none;
}


div#suiteBarRight{
background-color: #008CD2;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
div#suiteBarRight{
background-color: #008CD2\9;
color: #FFFFFF\9;
}

div#zz4_Menu_t{

color: #FFFFFF;
}

div#zz4_Menu{

color: #FFFFFF;
}


#s4-titlerow{ 
    display: none !important;
}
#pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 40px;color:white;}

#uppersearch{ 
    background-color:white;background:white;color:white !important;
    }



div#welcomeMenuBox span.ms-core-menu-root { background-color: white; color: white !important; }

#SearchBox { background-color: white; }

.s4-title h1 a, .s4-title h2, .s4-title h2 a{color:white !important;}


/* Change the color of the usernames*/
#welcomeMenuBox a
{
        Color:#FFFFFF;
}
.ms-core-menu-box {
        background-color:#008CD2}

#zz5_Menu_t{
 background-color:#008CD2;   
        }
#zz5_Menu{
 background-color:#008CD2;
        }

#zz1_ID_PersonalActionMenu
{
 background-color:#008CD2; }



/* Change the color of the App page tittle*/
#pageTitle a
{
        Color:#FFFFFF;
}










div#suiteBarLeft{
background-color: #008CD2\9;
color: #FFFFFF\9;
}

div#siteIcon{ 
display: none\9;
}


div#suiteBarRight{
background-color: #008CD2\9;
color: #FFFFFF\9;
}

div#zz4_Menu_t{

color: #FFFFFF\9;
}

div#zz4_Menu{

color: #FFFFFF\9;
}


#s4-titlerow{ 
    display: none !important\9;
}
#pageTitle {position: absolute\9; left: 400px\9; top: 40px\9;color:white\9;}

#uppersearch{ 
    background-color:white\9;background:white\9;color:white !important\9;
    }



div#welcomeMenuBox span.ms-core-menu-root { background-color: white\9; color: white !important\9; }

#SearchBox { background-color: white\9; }

.s4-title h1 a, .s4-title h2, .s4-title h2 a{color:white !important\9;}


/* Change the color of the usernames*/
#welcomeMenuBox a
{
        Color:#FFFFFF\9;
}
.ms-core-menu-box {
        background-color:#008CD2\9;}

#zz5_Menu_t{
 background-color:#008CD2\9;   
        }
#zz5_Menu{
 background-color:#008CD2\9;
        }

#zz1_ID_PersonalActionMenu
{
 background-color:#008CD2\9; }



/* Change the color of the App page tittle*/
#pageTitle a
{
        Color:#FFFFFF\9;
}
```

Comment: Ask users to upgrade to IE 9/10 at least :)

Comment: why i should ask them to upgrade ?, users might have IE version 8 which is a supported version for SharePoint 2013 as mentioned on this link msdn link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Comment: Try validating your custom css in visual studio using the Web Essentials tool

Comment: i check it using the F12 developer tools on IE. and yes if you access the SharePoint 2013 using IE version 8 the custom CSS will NOT work (will not make any effect to the layout).

Comment: It's really strange because I can display in IE8 all my custom css without any problems.
Do all the css rules in this file not work or only CSS3?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actully some of the Custome CSS will work but other will not . for example i have define the following CSS insdie my CustomeCSS . div#suiteBarLeft{
background-color: #008CD2;
color: #FFFFFF;
}




div#suiteBarRight{
background-color: #008CD2;
color: #FFFFFF;
}.  but both of them will not work and the default color for both Divs will be shown instead of the ones i have defined.

Comment: Try to test the hack, put `\9` on the end of the line like so: `div#suiteBarLeft{ background-color: #008CD2\9; color: #FFFFFF\9; }`

Comment: i copied the current CSS and i added \9 to all sections, but it will not work . if i use IE v9 and above it will work. i have edited my original question and i added my current customeCSS after adding the \9 to it.

Comment: Okay, please try one more thing, put `\0` instead of `\9` and if that does not work, put `\0/`.

Answer (score 2):

This thread might provide some clarity.  [Masterpage and CSS are not applied in IE 8](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72192/masterpage-and-css-are-not-applied-in-ie-8)  If IE8 is indeed loading CSS in a different order than more modern browsers, you might have to be more specific in your CSS as outlined in the thread.

Comment: i have added "!important;" to the background-color and i have also added "filter: none !important;". and the customCSS worked well. but not sure if adding these two chnages will affect other working CSS . till now i did not observe any side effects.what do u think ?

Comment: Here is a list of CSS and its compatibility by version of IE. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx important should not be a problem but there is an issue with filter.  See this StackOverflow thread for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593873/ie8-ignores-filter-css-styles

Comment: thanks for the rely. but as long as adding important and filter have fix my problem in IE8 , i will keep them for now. what risks i might face if i keep these two CSS components ??

Comment: The only issue I could anticipate would be the slight incompatibility of filter outlined in the Stack Overflow article I posted above.  Best of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349295/1340960) CSS hacks for various versions of Internet Explorer.

```
body { 
border:1px solid red; /* standard */
border:1px solid blue\9; /* IE8 and below */
*border:1px solid orange; /* IE7 and below */
_border:1px solid blue; /* IE6 */
}
```

Comment: but what will this help in my situation, can you advice ?

Comment: If you add the '\9' to your CSS lines, it should display it in a correct manner. Other option would be to manually add the classes to your HTML, but in SharePoint, if you mess with the master page HTML, you`d probably brake the entire site layout.

Comment: where i should add the \9 inside the custom CSS ?

Comment: See the example from the answer.

Comment: currently i am referncing the cusotmeCSS inside my seatle.master page using the following code:- <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom CSS/MyCustomeCss.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>   . so where i should place the \9 ???

Comment: Like the example says, you should place it inside your custom CSS file, in every class/id you wrote the CSS for :)

Comment: so i will have two version of the same class/id, one that ends with \9 and one without it  ?

Comment: Yepp, right on the spot.

Comment: In addition, there is a cool (by "cool" I mean free) app called [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) that runs on any popular browser and can emulate all IE versions, so you don`t have to install them.

Comment: yes i have used the F12 developer tools inside IE, and i have check the SP site under IE 8 and the problem is valid.